# Can't find column that exists in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, unicode-string

I am trying to do a group by but says:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("C:/Users/user/Desktop/Dataset.csv",encoding = 'UTF-8')
DT #until this all is fine
DT[, sum(as.numeric(Ποσότητα), na.rm=TRUE), by=.(user)]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , sum(as.numeric(Ποσότητα), na.rm = TRUE),
>   :    object 'Ποσότητα' not found
>   >

```
> colnames(DT)

"Ημερομηνία" "Χρήστης"    "Έργο"       "Εργασία"    "Ποσότητα" 


DT$Ποσότητα
  [1] "-"        "-"        "-"        "-"        "222"      "-"        "-"       
  [8] "5"        "1.460,65" "44"
```

its in Greek. Before I translated it but its best to show the actual words.

Answer (score 0):

Unicode characters are not handled very good in variable names, and basically it is not recommended to do so in R. Please change the column names into English translation as shown below:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)

df <- as.data.table(matrix(rnorm(50), ncol = 5))
colnames(df) <- c("Ημερομηνία", "Χρήστης", "Έργο", "Εργασία", "Ποσότητα" )
sum(df$Ποσότητα)
# Error: unexpected input in "sum(df$\"


colnames(df) <- c("Date", "User", "Work", "Job", "Quantity")
sum(df$Quantity)
# OK: [1] -0.08715537
```